# How to implement Scrum method in a 2-individuals team?

Tags: scrum

I'm a software developer and I have this project I am working on with a student (an internship). I don't know how to organize the tasks and how to assign them. At first, it was clear. But now we have a lot of work on this project and we lack a lot of organization.

We are working on 3 modules in an Enterprise Resource Planning (ERP) project (Odoo 10).

What is the best way to work with a small team of 2 individuals?

How to implement Scrum methods in our project?

How to manage tasks and bugs that take more than the expected time?

Answer (score 4):

If you only have two developers, you probably shouldn't be using Scrum without very carefully thinking about the intent of each ceremony and artifact and what it brings to your project.

From [the Scrum Guide's definition of the Development Team](http://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#team-dev):

> Fewer than three Development Team members decrease interaction and results in smaller productivity gains. Smaller Development Teams may encounter skill constraints during the Sprint, causing the Development Team to be unable to deliver a potentially releasable Increment.

If Scrum calls for a Development Team of between 3 and 9 people and you have fewer than 3 or more than 9, you shouldn't be calling what you are doing Scrum.

However, you can take advantage of some principles of Scrum: timeboxes, potentially releasable increments, a daily regroup and replan, planning for a given timebox, demonstrating functionality at the end of the timebox. Extreme Programming also offers some good ideas such as pair programming. You can also look at strategies such as Kanban for organizing and limiting work in progress.

Most defined methodologies are designed around solving problems that come with larger teams. In a group of 2, you may not be encountering those issues. But that doesn't mean you can't follow good practices that make sense for you.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but Alan [is right](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/23909/4271) that the [current Scrum Guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) recommends (but doesn’t mandate) the size of the Development Team in the “Development Team Size” section.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to work with a small team of 2 individuals?

With cognitive and creative efforts, there is no silver bullet best way.  Since you mentioned Scrum, refer to the [Manifesto for Agile Software Development](http://agilemanifesto.org) for a general philosophy on efficient collaboration to deliver valuable software.

> How to implement Scrum methods in our project?

[Scrum](https://scrumguides.org) is a framework (not method) for product (not project) development. While the artifacts, values, and events may be of value it may not be the best choice with only two developers.  Scrum neither requires nor restricts having three to nine members of the Development Team, it acknowledges the possible inefficiency and effectiveness with a team not within that size.  It also requires a Product Owner and Scrum Master.

> How to manage tasks and bugs that take more than the expected time?

This is a question that relies heavily on context.  In the agile software development philosophy, the effort is value driven and not plan driven.  It's most important to deliver a quality, valuable, working product and for both the creators and the consumers to respond to such changes than to follow a rigidly predefined schedule.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Scrum involves too much overhead for a pair of Devs, possibly why it is contraindicated in [the Scrum Guide](http://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html). Having no meaningful Product Owner makes Scrum unworkable.

If I was in that situation, I'd be tempted to experiment with [one day Sprints](https://hackernoon.com/one-day-sprints-1ce1f53a08b2), being sure to include a brief daily Review / demo / sharing with stakeholders.